# "Recently awarded to" out of order

Tags: support, badges

See: https://stackoverflow.com/badges/145/epic

I got the badge yesterday and I don't think 45 other got it since then.

Comment: Congratulation for getting the epic badge in 2 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order on badge pages is left-to-right, *then* top-to-bottom. So only three people have received the badge since you did.